# Is it appropriate to use Service for making update of user`s profile

Tags: android, service

I'm trying to develop a user profile with it's favorites, datas, etc. It it good to synchronize device's profile and remote profile of user with Service? Or usually it is enough to make request in separate thread?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use service make sure you use **IntentService**

If you use normal service it will run on Main thread which is not good approach in case of
asynchronous operations.

You will basically need IntentService and ResultReceiver.

You can check following to learn how to implement them

[how to create own download manager in android 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908375/how-to-create-own-download-manager-in-android-2-2/10908736#10908736)

Hope this help.