# Android code help needed

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-broadcast

I need to create an app where I have list of songs that are located on a remote server, and the user should be able to download them. Now my problem is how can I track download status(downloading, downloaded) in an example Download manager class, when im downloading from  another asyncTask class. Can someone help me by guiding me how can i do this in Android.

Comment: Lot of posts in Stackoverflow about the same topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908375/how-to-create-own-download-manager-in-android-2-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to implement it, step by step and post here your real code problem.

You should try baby steps like:

1. Connect to remote server;
2. List songs from the remote server;
3. Download one song; ...

You can try to split in in smaller taks if needed. If you already have something implemented, please post here your code for us to understand whats the problem.