# Getting message when downloading has been completed

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I'm trying to use **android default download manager** in my app, but problem is that i don't get any message in my app when download has been completed.
Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to register a BroadcastReceiver to know when it is completed:

```
    registerReceiver(completionReceiver, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
```

The Receiver:

```
    BroadcastReceiver completionReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {

     //here You know the download is complete, do whatever You want to do
}
   };
```

Comment: I use android 2.2, Is it possible in this version?

Comment: no, it´s added in API9, for alternative handling, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908375/how-to-create-own-download-manager-in-android-2-2